# Why ros2 std_msgs/Header removes `seq`?

Tags: ros, ros2, std-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm upgrading a ros1 package to ros2 and found that `std_msgs/Header` msg has changed.

in ros1: https://github.com/ros/std_msgs/blob/kinetic-devel/msg/Header.msg

```
# sequence ID: consecutively increasing ID 
uint32 seq
```

while in ros2: https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/rolling/std_msgs/msg/Header.msg

`seq` is removed. Why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/418217/why-ros2-std_msgs/header-removes-%60seq%60?/) by [felixf4xu](https://answers.ros.org/users/120001/felixf4xu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2023-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [this document](http://design.ros2.org/articles/changes.html): "The field has been deprecated for a long time and was not set consistently in ROS 1."
In many cases the subscribers would ignore the sequence number, so it made sense to remove it to reduce overhead. Note that this header is shared across a large variety of messages, so removal does have an impact.

---

Originally posted by [Bernd Pfrommer](https://answers.ros.org/users/53718/bernd-pfrommer/) with karma: 78 on 2023-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1